# ITypeInfo and fast searching for function signature

Tags: winapi, com, typelib, typeinfo

Maybe I'm blind, but how did Microsoft think of finding a function signature quickly using the ITypeInfo interface? How do others do it better than me?

In order to find a function, you need a member ID, which you have specified in the interface, and the InvokeKind, i.e. whether it is a func, a property get, let or set. In order to carry out an invocation, whether with DispCallFunc or Invoke from IDispatch, you need the function signature in order to set the parameters correctly.

This is where ITypeInfo comes into play. The way seems to me to first get the MemberID if the function name is known. However, there can be up to three different signatures in COM for a function, which must be determined after the InvokeKind.

My way to find the function signature:

First you have to fetch a pointer to GetTypeAttr.
There in the TYPEATTR struct you have to find out, how many function member entries are existing.
And because FUNCDESC entries are **index** based, you have to loop over all FUNCDESC entries to find a match for the combination MemberID, InvokeKind.
And finally you have to release all stuff to free the memory.

This job has to be done very often. Am I stupid or is it Microsoft? Why isn't there a quick way to do this? Or is there a quicker way?

Comment: *"This job has to be done very often."* - No, not really. The dispatch interface is mostly meant for scripting environments (like VBScript). Native code (C, C++, etc.) can instead use the raw COM interface. If the object only exposes the `IDispatch` interface (and you have a type library), you can use the [`#import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) directive of the compiler to have it generate all the plumbing required to make a call into the dispatch interface from native code.

Comment: IDispatch and COM-Automation *is not* COM, it's a technology that sits above "raw" COM and that was not designed to be the most performant thing. It was designed to be late bound, dynamic and targeted for scripting or languages such as VB, VBA, VBScript, JScript, etc. Note typelib/typeinfo (eg: hard metadata description) is optional to use IDispatch, you only need a dispid (supposed to be stable) and a list of arguments that are all COM-Automation.

Comment: Not true. I am writing an interpreter to support dual and invoke interface. So when you are writing this, you need to fetch the information from the typelibs you intend to dispatch. The API call for dual interface is DispCallFunc, and when you ever have tried to use this function, you really know, that you need explicit information about the parameters.

Comment: DispCallFunc is as well the key api call for C++ functions of DLLs you like to dispatch.

Comment: DispCallFunc is just a wrapper over IDispatch::Invoke. COM automation doesn't mandate how IDispatch implementors are supposed to work. Typelibs are *not* mandatory to implement IDispatch. Some support IDispatch w/o a typelib, some support IDispatch w a typelib. Some have only IUnknown-derived. Some support both IDispatch + IUnknown (this is what dual is). Some support changing arguments type and only use VARIANT types (as VariantChangeType is a powerful function), etc. Don't assume anything.

Comment: If you're writing your own system capable of discovering the API shape of unknown components at run time then you have to write a parser for the function signatures, construct the arguments, and manage resources. I don't know of any APIs that help with that, but that doesn't mean much as that's not something I ever looked into. You could give the `#import` directive on an arbitrary TLB a try and see if the generated header files provide any hints.

Comment: And even if you call Invoke of IDispatch directly, you need to know exactly what you do and you need to use the parameters of typeinfo. Sometimes even for optional parameters.

Comment: IInspectabe, I did all stuff for this, parsing, tokenizing. The compiler and interpreter is raedy and running. I just want to speed up and I am wondering about the ineffective way to find the function signature of ITypeInfo.

Comment: Simon Mourier, DispCallFunc is allowing you to dispatch even DLL funcs like user32 or kernel32 functions. It is not a wrapper to IDispatch->Invoke.

Comment: DispCallFunc is even officially documented as a wrapper over Invoke. It's just used for (old) cross platform (mac, ppc, mips) support. If you know everything already, why do you come here and ask questions.

Comment: Simon, I have not asked for the use of DispCallFunc, I have taken months to make this rarely documented function to work. My question was to speed up the search for function signature in typeinfo. Please please do not be mad with me. When you like to get it work with records, pointers, and all different data types BYVAL/BYREF it is a hard job with many disappointments.

Comment: DispCallFunc: the help of MS is not telling the whole truth. HRESULT DispCallFunc(void *pvInstance, ULONG_PTR  oVft, CALLCONV   cc, VARTYPE vtReturn,
UINT cActuals, VARTYPE *prgvt, VARIANTARG **prgpvarg, VARIANT *pvargResult); If you set the first parameter to NULL, you can give a DLL function address for second parameter, and you can invoke with it, whatever you want

Comment: One way to speed things up would be to walk over `ITypeInfo` once and store the information obtained therefrom in the internal data structures. These data structures could provide fast lookup by whatever criteria you need.

Comment: Did you tried [ITypeInfo::GetIDsOfNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-itypeinfo-getidsofnames)?

Comment: A quick research for [the example of GetIDsOfNames](https://github.com/cran/excel.link/blob/f50b13fd674e98759859335df8510dca46fa0604/src/connect.cpp#L399) which gives the mapped IDs based on the member name and the member's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer is that when using IDispatch it is up to the programmer to get the number of arguments right. Once the number of arguments is right the signature is not generally checked on the call side, Instead the callee attempts to coerce arguments to the needed types (and there are entire libraries dedicated to easing this process). Note that for this part getting the signature is fast because it is known what function is being invoked.

For example, the usual IDispatch-to-dual interface call (DispCallFunc) will check that the argument count is at least as many as are needed, as well as perform argument coercion for you (if possible).
Even if you are implementing a pure dispinterface you can use the VariantChangeType API to perform coercion to the correct type. In neither case does the caller check beforehand that the arguments are what the function expects.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use DispCallFunc? I am writing a compiler/interpreter, and whenever you are not setting the right variant type given by the function description in typeinfo and call mode (byref/byval) the DispCallFunc is failing, once with error code, once with crash

Comment: And this is not answer of my question. I want to get a fast search of iTypeInfo function signature with close proximity to API and storage. I do not use other libraries with additional loss of time (I would like to).

Comment: @RenéRössler I think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Your compiler/interpreter shouldn't need to know a signature ahead of time, that is the caller's responsibility. You don't need to search `ITypeInfo` to `Invoke()` a COM function, just its `DISPID` (you can get it at runtime using `IDispatch.GetIDsOfNames()` if you don't look it up earlier), call type (based on call syntax), and array of param values. If the caller mismatches the parameters, the call fails with an error code and parameter index. I think you are making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Remy, this is working for Invoke of IDispatch, but you get problems as well with i.e. 1) optional parameters, because the calling order is from last to first, and the first can as well be the value to be setted in PROPPUT, PROPPUTREF - 2) BYREF parameters, where you need to get the result parameters returned in callee, where you need exactly the VARTYPE and Calling Type (IN / IN OUT). This is much more critical when using DispCallFunc for Interfaces other IDispatch or DLL function calls

Comment: So it is necessary to know the parameters at minimum VARTYPE, OPTIONAL (or not) and you need to read the default value when optional and not VARIANT, and the level of indirection BYVAL / * / **, BEFORE you make the call to Invoke or DispCallFunc

Comment: Much of it can be done on design time when compiling and caching the parameters in a way you need it, but it is always necessary to look into iTypeInfo or you let the user give you the parameter definition in a way like DECLARE FUNCTION

Comment: If you build a compiler with named parameters (I did not), you also need to know if the name is existing in function declaration and the ordinal position in function call, I guess

Comment: You also need to know if last parameter is PARAMARRAY, where the number of additional parameters is free to set, and check the minimum parameter number for the call.